# How to integrate react native checkbox with formik

Tags: reactjs, react-native, formik, yup

Note: We can not use any other library like react-native-element only 'react-native' and 'formik'.

I am not able to integrate a react-native checkbox with formik. Need to set the value of formik form.

If I use the InputFields with formic it is working with the same code.

**Checkbox.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { CheckBox, Text, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';

const Checkbox = ({ children, value, handleChange }) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <View>
        <CheckBox
          type={'checkbox'}
          value={value}
          onValueChange={handleChange}
          checked={value}
        />
        <Text>{children}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Checkbox;
```

**Main.js**

```
  <Formik
      initialValues={{
          financiallyResponsible: true,
      }}
      onSubmit={(values, { resetForm }) => {
        console.log(values);
      }}
    >
      {({
        handleChange,
        handleSubmit,
        values,
       }) => (
        <View>
          <Checkbox
             value={values?.financiallyResponsible}
             handleChange={handleChange('financiallyResponsible')}
          >
            Financially Responsible
          </Checkbox>
          <Button onPress={handleSubmit} title="Submit"></Button>
        </View>
      )}

    </Formik>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `setFieldValue(fieldName, nextValue)` like [doc](https://formik.org/docs/guides/react-native#the-gist) says:

> ... instead of directly assigning the callbacks to props, because we
> have to get the fieldName from somewhere and with React Native we
> can't get it automatically like in web (using input name attribute).
> You can also use setFieldValue(fieldName, value) and
> setFieldTouched(fieldName, bool) as an alternative.

**Checkbox.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { CheckBox, Text, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';

const Checkbox = ({ children, ...props }) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <View>
        <CheckBox
          type={'checkbox'}
          {...props}
        />
        <Text>{children}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Checkbox;
```

**Main.js**

```
  <Formik
      initialValues={{
          financiallyResponsible: true,
      }}
      onSubmit={(values, { resetForm }) => {
        console.log(values);
      }}
    >
      {({
        handleChange,
        handleSubmit,
        values,
        setFieldValue
       }) => (
        <View>
          <Checkbox
             value={values?.financiallyResponsible}
             onValueChange={nextValue => setFieldValue('financiallyResponsible', nextValue)}
          >
            Financially Responsible
          </Checkbox>
          <Button onPress={handleSubmit} title="Submit"></Button>
        </View>
      )}

    </Formik>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hey @BrunoCardoso for some reason this code is still not working.

Answer (score 2):

This helps to get it to work, but thank you @Bruno your suggestion helped me.

**checkbox.js**

```
<View>
      <View>
        <CheckBox
          type={'checkbox'}
          value={value}
          onValueChange={handleChange}
          //   checked={value}
          {...props}
        />
        <Text>{children}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
```

**Main.js**

```
 <Formik
      initialValues={{
          financiallyResponsible: true,
      }}
      onSubmit={(values, { resetForm }) => {
        console.log(values);
      }}
    >
      {({
        handleChange,
        handleSubmit,
        values,
        setFieldValue
       }) => (
        <View>
          <Checkbox
             value={values?.financiallyResponsible}
             handleChange={nextValue => setFieldValue('financiallyResponsible', nextValue)}
          >
            Financially Responsible
          </Checkbox>
          <Button onPress={handleSubmit} title="Submit"></Button>
        </View>
      )}

    </Formik>
  );
}
```